# Data Entry Activity form

Tags: android

i'm trying to create an activity that looks similar to this (circled in red):

[image: Example]

I'm wondering if they're using a Listview to do this?

I also am wondering, how did they do the "reminders" section where it expands and retracts based on how many reminders you put in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if they're using a Listview to do this?

Unlikely. That is probably a `GridLayout`, perhaps wrapped in a `ScrollView`.

> I also am wondering, how did they do the "reminders" section where it expands and retracts based on how many reminders you put in.

Add more children to the `GridLayout` in the appropriate positions.

Comment: i'm gonna give this a shot and see how i can do it. I guess for the dividers they're views too right?

Comment: @user1848850: Yes, possibly a `View` with a specific background nine-patch. Since the Calendar app is on the emulator, you should be able to bring this up in Hierarchy View and see precisely what they are doing.

Comment: i wish it were, it's not an app on my emulator, maybe i'll see if i can try and find it and install it on the emulator